# How to self join in JPA in Entity class and CreateQuery

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, jpa-2.0, jpql

In my program I have a search function for the manager's name. 
In my Database the manager id of an employee is equal to the employee id of another employee. now in my sql I self join the employee e to employee m

```
SELECT
e.EMPLOYEE_ID      AS empId,
e.FIRST_NAME       AS empFirstName,
e.LAST_NAME        AS empLastName,
m.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || m.LAST_NAME AS empMgrName
FROM
EMPLOYEES e
LEFT JOIN
EMPLOYEES m ON e.MANAGER_ID = m.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE
LOWER(m.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || m.LAST_NAME) LIKE '%"ManagerName"%'
```

How can I do this in play create query. do I have to do something with my create query which has

```
String strMgr = StringUtil.isDataNull(search.get("empMgrName"));
query.append(" FROM ");
query.append("    Employees e  ");
query.append(" WHERE 1 = 1 ");
if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(strMgr)) {
  query.append(" AND  ");
  query.append("    LOWER(m.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || m.LAST_NAME) LIKE :empMgrName ");
}
query.append(" ORDER BY ");
query.append("   EMPLOYEE_ID ");
query.append(" ASC  ");

Query listEmpQuery = JPA.em().createQuery(query.toString(), Employees.class);
if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(strMgr))
listEmpQuery.setParameter("empMgrName", "%" + strMgr.toLowerCase() + "%");
listEmpQuery.setFirstResult((page - 1) * 10);
listEmpQuery.setMaxResults(10);

List<Employees> listEmp = listEmpQuery.getResultList();

return listEmp;
```

and with my Employee Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "EMPLOYEES_SEQ", sequenceName = "EMPLOYEES_SEQ")
public class Employees {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EMPLOYEES_SEQ")
public Long EMPLOYEE_ID;

public String FIRST_NAME;

public String LAST_NAME; 

public String MANAGER_ID;
```

Comment: why don't you just create a nativequery?

Comment: 1. Respect the Java naming conventions. 2. Name your entity Employee, not Employees: an instance of this entity is **one** employee. 3. Use a `@ManyToOne Employee manager` association instead of storing the ID of the manager. 4. Once you have that, the query becomes trivial: `select ... from Employee e join e.manager m where ...`

Comment: @ScaryWombat my trainer told me that createQuery is more efficient than NativeQuery. So im trying to learn JPQL Language

Comment: @JBNizet Noted. Thank You for the reply. i will try the following. in the naming conventions of my Employee entity that is because that is the column name in the database that im using. ill just use Column(name) then. thank you :)

Comment: JB Nizet is right. Do you have also a Manager Entity?

Comment: @RezaPayambari i have no manager entity im thinking of using a self join kind of method in the Employee.class

Comment: ok, then in that case, just follow what JB Nizet said. But it makes sense just when Employee and Manager are the same. If it was me, I would make a Person Entity and then extends my Employee and Manager from the Person in case of some changes in future.

Comment: You don't need two classes. That is not what was suggested originally. An exact example of what the mappings suggsted by JB Nizet should look like can be found here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/

Comment: @AlanHay thanks for the link. it proven to be very helpful. i got it to work on jpql thanks :)